# Cannot bind fields using InputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, fieldsets

I'm using an apex repeat to build a modal using a fieldset.

**The following works fine:**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!currentFieldSet}"  var="C"> 
    <apex:outputLabel >{!C.Label}</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputText html-placeholder="{!currentCase[C.fieldPath]}"></apex:inputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

I see the field values as placeholder text in my fields.

However, due to the fieldset containing a lookup field, I would like to bind the values to input fields like so:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!currentFieldSet}"  var="C"> 
    <apex:outputLabel >{!C.Label}</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!currentCase[C.fieldPath]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

**However, this gives the following error:**

```
Variable is not visible: [ITSSCnC].currentCase
```

currentCase is a property defined as so:

```
 public static Case currentCase {get;set;} {currentCase = new Case();}
```

However I do not think this is the issue, due to the first piece of code working. Does anybody have any insight into what is going on?

**Additional Info:**

This is how I'm populating currentCase (which is working):

```
 currentCase = [SELECT Subject, Status, Priority, Contact.Name FROM Case WHERE Id =: caseId LIMIT 1];
```

This is how I'm populating the fieldset:

```
public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> readFieldSet()
{
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get('Case');
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName);
    return fieldSetObj.getFields();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I changed the following:

Original:

```
public static Case currentCase {get;set;} {currentCase = new Case();}
```

Fixed:

```
global Case currentCase {get;set;} {currentCase = new Case();}
```

I can only guess as to why, however it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the first part works, but it should not be static, the following should work

```
public Case currentCase {get;set;}

public MyController() {
    currentCase = new Case();
}
```

I guess the difference is, that `apex:inputField` is way more complex, so it needs a better access to the record than `inputText` does, just a thought.